# How do I display button in an Alexa card

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to display a button in alexa card,
when user click on button it will navigate some browser or display more text.
I cannot find any documentation to do this.So please provide any idea or information to do this using Alexa response builder

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set buttons or any other external links inside the `Simple` or `Standard` card other than links for account linking. There are suggestions out there of achieving similar functionality by including `Html` in the response, but none of them will work.

As the official from Amazon Alexa team quotes [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/200446/how-to-call-another-intent-by-including-a-clickabl.html),

> The Standard card can generally only display plain text for a title
>   and content, as well as a place for an image (you use a URL here but
>   cannot include clickable links).

Comment: Is there any way to do this

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to do so as of now.